# Does rails and other gems install documentation anywhere when you install them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

And where can I find it? I'm running OSX.

In addition I have to do a lot of work offline while travelling so if anyone can offer any tips for downloadable documentation please let me know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have installed your gems the "normal" way, they install rdoc documentation.

Just run `gem server` in your console and go to http://localhost:8808 in your browser. There you'll find all available Gems and the RDoc documentation

Comment: So I tried this and it worked, except that there doesn't appear to be any documentation. For example, under rails 'rdoc', it says page generated by rdoc generator, but doesn't contain any actual docs, as if it didn't have access to the source to build them. Do I have to run some kind of build command first?

Comment: check you **$HOME/.gemrc** file, if it includes *gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc*, need to remove it and reinstall gems. **gem server** was popular before when everybody installs rdoc and ri

Comment: I don't seem to have a .gemrc file. I didn't set any special options so I'm assuming the docs should have been installed.

Comment: Yeah, seems like Rails is somewhat special in that way ... It doesn't generate RDoc. So for Rails I would go with the solution mikhailov presented. For the rest you can use RDoc

Answer (score 1):

http://railsapi.com provides you to download offline documentation for:

- Rails 2.2.2, 2.3.8, 3.0.8
- Ruby 1.8, 1.9.2
- Authlogic
- AWS-S3
- EventMachine
- Haml
- Hpricot
- Nokogiri
- Rack
- Rspec
- Sinatra

The downloadable file has wonderful jQuery search functionality, so it's pretty useful

Comment: it's **sdoc** format, you can try to merge standard docs to sdoc

Answer (score 0):

@klaustopher's answer didn't work for me directly, so here is how I got this to work for the rspec-expectations gem:

1. Install gem documentation by either

   - using the `--rdoc` flag: `gem install --rdoc rspec-expectations`
   - or by installing rdocs for all gems: `gem rdoc --all`
2. Run rdoc server.

`gem server`

3. Go to `http://localhost:8808` in my browser.

Caveat: at a first glance the rdoc for `rspec-expectations` is pretty useless.  I bet there is a better way to do this.